# jquery AJAX get request cross browser issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
searchCompanyExecutives: function(criteria, callback) {
        var params = $j.extend({
            type: "GET",
            dara: criteria,
            url: "/wa/rs/company_executives?random=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * (new Date()).getTime() + 1),
            dataType: "json"
        }, callback);

        $j.ajax(params);
    },
```

and in the above code criteria is like a JSON
    {
        'companyId':'1',
        'beginNum':'42'
    }

In the backend I am expecting data as a "query String params" we wrote this code 2 years ago at that time it was working fine.
and now in new versions of IE and firefox we are not able to get those query parameters in the backend

Comment: dara: criteria, should be data: criteria,

Comment: What are the specific issues? Console erors?

Comment: provide backend code

Comment: `daRa` => `daTa` as said by @ParthPatel and after this patched, in FF, on `dev tools>network`, do you get your request ? do you have some error in `>console` ?

Comment: As a side note, i'd use `cache: false` to avoid having to add randomized timestamp in url. And anyway, i really don't see why you are randomized it, i mean just a timestamp should be enough. That's said, without posting any relevant debug info as error, i don't see how you are expecting anyone to answer your 'question'. And btw, this `{ 'companyId':'1', 'beginNum':'42' }` is invalid JSON notation. I think you deserve a downvote, sorry about that

Comment: you need to use dataType jsonp. make server allow to add  cross domain.

Comment: sorry @ParthPatel Its typo

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Why that? It isn't a cross domain request

Comment: Backend code for above is String idStr = (String) httpServletRequest.getParameter("companyId");

Comment: @PradeepChalla Can you tell us more as how do you debug it?! Since two years, you didn't change anything in code, jq version, server config or whatever? I guess you made some upgrades... And of course, your code is still working in older IE versions e.g and chrome? Did you at least checked it?

Comment: As I said It was written 2 years back and I didn't wrote this code and the We didn't changed any version changes in the application.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi We are not using any cross domain requests . We are using Jboss server and doing an normal ajax call.

Comment: @A.Wolff When I tried to debug, as a default functionality of jQuery Ajax get  [jQuery] (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) if we send any json in data it will convert into query string params. but in my case for some specific IE/firefox versions query string params are not going to backend

Comment: @PradeepChalla Which FF & IE version? What if you don't set `random` as query string but use instead cache false? How looks like `criteria` in FF, IE & chrome? Etc... You have to debug it on your side, nothing really we can help you regarding the info you provided

Comment: I tried with IE latest Edge version and in firefox version 42 and earlier versions its working. The url is formed like this if we try in Chrome **localhost/wa/rs/company_executives?random=1449660151205&companyId=2534&beginNum=1&endNum=6**  but if try in IE or firefix after the random, other params are not getting appended ex: **localhost/wa/rs/company_executives?random=1449660151205** and even I tried with removing random from the url and the result is same

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with prototype.js toQueryParams function which takes operates on url hash value. In our case we are taking hash value from the browser and converting it into object by using this toQueryParams method. In firefox and IE latest versions hash value is **companyId%3D2534%26beginNum‌​%3D1%26endNum%3D6** but in other browsers its coming like **companyId=2534&beginNum‌​=1&endNum=6** so inn the prevus case its not decode before calling the method toQueryParams. So this is causing the issue. Finally I converted this hash in decode format by using decodeURIComponent and finally its working. and the final conclusion is if you take hash value and try to conbvert into toQueryParams then this cause the issue in latest browsers.

Thanks everyone for helping in it.